# Add a character between 2 bytes in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

What is the easiest way to do this?

I have a string like this.

```
var string='0ABAFFACBDFE...';
```

I want to convert it to this.

```
var newString= '0A,BA,FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..FF,AC,BD,FE ..';
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/javascript-split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks and use `join`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
string.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(',');
```

Split the string by 2 chars, into an Array, then join the array back into a string with the comma on the end of every string in the array.