# divide base64 encoded string into small chunks

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

i am trying to send a `base64 encoded` data to server but at a time i can send `65535` bytes of data to server and my string size of `base64 encoded` image is `111751` bytes.

so how can i divide the content of `base64 encoded` string into small piece of `65535` bytes of block in javascript or jquery.

i am using `jquery.base64.js`

```
function readImage(input) {
    if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {

        var blockString = e.target.result;
            // here its showing 111751 bytes
        console.log(blockString.length); 




        };       

        FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );


    }
}
```

Comment: check this question and accepted answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/javascript-split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/javascript-split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks)

Comment: so there is no need to separate it by byte i can directly split it into N numbre of string ?