# regular expression is not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, regex, cordova

i m using regular expression to divide string data into specified number of blocks , everything works well in browser but when i try the same page in `phonegap` it doesn't work at all.

here is my code where `blockString[1]` contains the string data and `resSize` represents where to divide the string.

```
var pattern = "/.{1,"+resSize+"}/";
var rex = new RegExp(pattern,"g");  
var finalBlocks = blockString[1].match(rex);
```

but `finalBlocks` always returns null in `phonegap`

following is the data which is a `base64` representation of image , its a content of `blockString[1]`

`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`

Comment: then why its matching in a browser ? , ya content of `blockString[1]` is visible when i print it in a console.log

Comment: i have posted the data just now

Comment: Is it your intention to match parts between slashes or do you just want to split the data into blocks of a maximum size? Because you do not need to include slashes to mark the beginning and end of the regular expression when you use the `RegExp` constructor (see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description)?

Comment: let me try by removing slashes

Comment: even after removing it the result is same previously i was using it as `var rex = new RegExp("/.{1,"+resSize+"}/","g");`

Comment: But you are still including the slashes!?! It should look like this: `var rex = new RegExp(".{1,"+resSize+"}","g");` This will match blocks of size `{1,resSize}`

Comment: ya i tried removing too but no effect , look at this question i wanted to achieve this but its not working in phonegap `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727096/divide-base64-encoded-string-into-small-chunks`

Comment: Ok. Then I would guess that something is wrong with either `blockString` or `resSize` when you run the code on the device/emulator. Because RegExp are basically working correctly in Phonegap.

Comment: yeah it was my bad the problem was `resSize` was coming in a floating number

Comment: Ok. So I'll make an answer out of this and would be glad if you accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all:** you should remove the slashes within the pattern string unless your intention is to match expressions between two slashes. The [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description) does not expect the pattern to be surrounded by slashes.

Despite that, it looks fine so I would guess that something is wrong with either `blockString` or `resSize` when you run the code on the device/emulator.

From the comments:

> yeah it was my bad the problem was `resSize` was coming in a floating
>   number – Hunt