# Split string into parts of defined length

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string into parts with a defined length. This means if I have a given string like `"1234567890"` and want to split it in parts with length `3` then I expect the result `["123", "456", "789", "0"]`. To achive this I have found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349616/2577116

Now, I also want to split not starting at the beginning but at the end of the string. The expected result would be `["1", "234", "567", "890"]`.

Therefore I used and modified the solution above and came up with this:

```
function (str, len, reversed) {
        //create array from string
    var _parts = str.split(""),
        _size = Math.ceil(_parts.length/len),
        _ret  = [],
        _offset;

    //should give ["123", "456", "789", "0"]
    if (!reversed) {
        for (var _i=0; _i<_size; _i++) {
            _offset = _i * len;
            _ret[_i] = _parts.slice(_offset, _offset+len).join("");
        }
    }
    //should give ["1", "234", "567", "890"]
    else {
        //reverse input
        _parts.reverse();
        //apply same algorithm as above but don't join yet
        for (var _j=0; _j<_size; _j++) {
            _offset = _j * len;
            _ret[_j] = _parts.slice(_offset, _offset+len);
        }
        //bring each subitem back to right order, join
        _ret.forEach(function (item, i) {
            _ret[i] = item.reverse().join("");
        });
        //reorder items
        _ret.reverse();
    }

    return _ret;
}
```

This seems to work pretty well.
**I'm asking for some better/simplified solution as mine feels a little bulky.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
    function foo(str,len,rev) {
      var result = [];
      if (rev && str.length%len != 0) {
        result.push(str.substr(0, str.length % len));
        str=str.substr(str.length % len);
      }

      for (var i=0; i<str.length; i+=len) {
        result.push(str.substr(i,len));
      }
      return result;
    }
```

The if statement will first check if reversed is true and if so it will calculate the rest when dividing the length of the string with the chunk size (check the [modulo operation %](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)). Then using the function "substr", that takes a starting position and a length, to get the first element of the list.

The for loop will iterate through the string "len" characters at the time and again using the function "substr" cut the string in to pieces of length "len" and add them to the list result.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.

Comment: I have edited your function to avoid the empty string in the array: https://jsfiddle.net/kheL86d8/ Please update your answer with the corrected version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by rearranging the string and Using the same `chunkString` function that you pointed at.

```
> chunkString(s.split('').reverse().join(''), 3).map(function(v){return v.split('').reverse().join('');}).reverse()
< ["1", "234", "567", "890"]
```

The `split, reverse, join` are used to convert string to list,  reverse, and then convert back to string.
Readeable code -

```
chunkString(
    s.split('').reverse().join(''),
    3
).map(
    function(v){
        return v.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
).reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer RegEx:

```
"1234567890".match(/(.{1,3})|(.{1,})/g)
```

Output:

```
["123", "456", "789", "0"]
```

For **Reverse**:

```
var splitLength = 3
var _str = "1234567890"
var startSubStringLength = _str.length % splitLength

_str.match(new RegExp("(^.{1," + startSubStringLength + "})|(.{1,3})|(.{1,})", "g"))
```

Output:

```
["1", "234", "567", "890"]
```

**Complete Function**

```
var _mySplit = function(str, splitLength, doReverse) {
    var _regEx = new RegExp("(.{" + splitLength + "})|(.{1,})", "g");
    if(doReverse) {
        var startSubStringLength = str.length % splitLength
        if(startSubStringLength > 0) {
            _regEx = new RegExp("(^.{1," + startSubStringLength + "})|(.{1," + splitLength +  "})|(.{1,})", "g")
        }
    }
    return str.match(_regEx)
}
```

Output:

```
_mySplit("1234", 3, false)
["123", "4"]
_mySplit("1234", 3, true)
["1", "234"]
_mySplit("1234567890", 3, true)
["1", "234", "567", "890"]
_mySplit("1234567890", 3, false)
["123", "456", "789", "0"]
```

Comment: Throws an error when used with `_str="123456789"` -> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(^.{1,0})|(.{1,3})/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier.

Comment: @Fidel90 ok, fixing it

Comment: @Fidel90 Fixed, please check

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Steps:

1. Reverse the string
2. Split it into group of three characters
3. Reverse the string

Code:

```js
var str = '1234567890';
var rev = str.split('').reverse().join('');

var matches = rev.match(/([0-9]{1,3})/g).reverse().map(function(el) {
  return el.split('').reverse().join('');
});
console.log(matches);
```

**Even shorter**(*Less Redable*)

```js
var matches = '1234567890'.split('').reverse().join('').match(/([0-9]{1,3})/g).reverse().map(function(el) {
  return el.split('').reverse().join('');
});
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```js
function mySplit (str, len, reversed) {
        //create array from string
  var _parts = str.split(""),
      _size = Math.ceil(_parts.length/len),
      _ret  = [],
      _offset;


  for (var _i=0; _i<_size; _i++) {
    _offset = Math.abs((reversed ? _parts.length : 0 ) - (_i * len));
    var sliceStart = reversed ? Math.max(0, _offset - len) : _offset;
    var sliceEnd = reversed ? _offset : _offset + len;
    _ret.push(_parts.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd).join(""));
  }
  reversed && _ret.reverse();


  return _ret;
}

var log = document.getElementById('log');

log.innerHTML += "string : 1234567890";
log.innerHTML += "\nreversed:" + mySplit("1234567890", 3, true)
log.innerHTML += "\nnot reversed:" + mySplit("1234567890", 3, false)

log.innerHTML += "\n\nstring : 123456789";
log.innerHTML += "\nreversed:" + mySplit("123456789", 3, true)
log.innerHTML += "\nnot reversed:" + mySplit("123456789", 3, false)
```

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i made.

```
var string = '1234567890';
var chunks = 3;

console.log( sliceIt(string, chunks, true) );
console.log( sliceIt(string, chunks, false) );



function sliceIt( str , steps , rev ) {

  var iterations  = Math.ceil(str.length); // for the loop
  var returnArray = [];
  var strLen      = str.length;
  var modulo      = strLen % steps; // for reverse purposes

  // if modulo is 0 then no action needed. returns the modulo if both true
  var firstStep       = (rev === true) && (modulo != 0) ? modulo : false;  

  for (i=0; i < iterations;) {        

      // pushing to array
      returnArray.push(str.substr( i , firstStep || steps ));   

      // increment the right way 
      i+= firstStep || steps; 

      // first step done.. deactivate
      firstStep = false; 
    }
    return returnArray;
  }
```