# how to split a string two by two in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I have a string variable that has exactly 44 characters:

```
02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476
```

I need to split it into an array like this:

```
arr[0]=02
arr[1]=08
.
.
arr[21]=76
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I know it must be easy but I couldn't find the necessary jquery functions to do it. Here is the pseudocode:

```
var s = "02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476";
var tmp;
var index=0;
for i =0 to 21
  arr[0] = mid(s,index,2); // take two characters starting from "index"
  index=index+2;
  next i
```

I just need the syntax.

Comment: really not complicated and there are a variety of ways to do it...what have you tried?

Comment: @charlietfl I know the way but I don't know the jquery syntax enough.

Comment: there is no jQuery involved for something like this

Comment: This has been answered before [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/javascript-split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could split using [**`.match`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
"02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476".match(/\d{2}/g)
```

that returns

```
[
 "02", "08", "15", "16", "17", "18", "21", "24", "29", "36", "37", 
 "47", "50", "56", "58", "65", "66", "68", "71", "73", "74", "76"
]
```

Comment: Mentioning that it returns `["02", "08", "15", "16", "17", "18", "21", "24", "29", "36", "37", "47", "50", "56", "58", "65", "66", "68", "71", "73", "74", "76"]` will be extra ++

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476';
var arr = new Array();
var x = 0;
if(x < 22){
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i=i+2){
   arr[x] = str.substring(i, i+2);
  x++;
}
  }

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=[]
a="02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476".split('')
while(a.length) n.push(a.splice(0,2).join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call any symbol from string using: `charAt()` function

JS:

```
var data = '02081516171821242936374750565865666871737476';
var res = new Array();

for (var i = 0, count = 0; i < data.length; i += 2, count++ ) {

    res[count] = data.charAt(i) + data.charAt(i+1);

}
```