# How do I make nested matches with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a group of words and then match another group within those found. How can I do it with regexp? What is the general way for doing this?

For example I need to find words longer than 8 letters and then split all those words by groups of 4 letters, so that I can insert a dash or any other symbol with javascript.

So if my text is:

`A full Reference & Help is available in the Library, or watch the video Tutorial.`

my regexp must match

`['Refe', 'renc', 'avai', 'labl', 'Tuto', 'rial']`

I know that I can select long words with something like `/[a-z]{8,}/ig` and then I need to apply somethig like `/[a-z]{3}/ig`. So how do I combine the two?
If I just do `/([a-z]{8,})[a-z]{4}/ig` it doesn't give me the right match.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the regex? Are you using it inside a `replace`?

Comment: @Bergi, yes I'll use it inside a replace();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=[a-z]{4})[a-z]{4}|[a-z]{4}(?=[a-z]{4})/ig
```

But JS doesn't have lookbehind.

In general, you would just match the 8-or-more-letter words, and then do your custom processing to each of the matches in a second step:

```
str.replace(/[a-z]{8,}/ig, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/[a-z]{4}(?=[a-z])/ig, "$&-"); // or whatever
});
```

Comment: @torazaburo: Ah, right, we'd need lookbehind as well

Comment: `return match.replace(/^([a-z]{4})([a-z]{4})\w*/ig, "$1-$2");`

Comment: If the word is exactly 8 letter, it will - to the end: A full Refe-renc-e & Help is avai-labl-e in the Library, or watch the video Tuto-rial-."

Comment: @OriDrori: Then use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7033639/1048572) and `.join("-")`. Or the lookahead as in the updated answer. Or whatever :-)

Comment: @Bergi, thanks! I tested your regexp for php and it works exactly as it should. Too bad it doesn't work for JS...