# Split string into array of n length

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

So I have a string that I need to split into an array, for example:

```
"1234567890"
```

I need to be able to split it like:

```
"1234567890".break(2) = ["12345", "67890"]
```

and:

```
"1234567890".break(3) = ["123", "456","7890"]
```

So I don't want it to split it into an array of equal parts, I want to split the string into an array of length `n`. How do you think I would go about doing this?

No, its not this: [regex - Split large string in n-size chunks in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't want to have each string in the array be N,

Comment: I want the array's total length to be N(Pressed enter accidently :/)

Comment: Ok. I understand the difference now.

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate?

Comment: @Alexander, Nina Scholz, The problem looks a bit different than the older one. (I apologize for my flag initially, I didn't find an option to undo my flag.)

Comment: @TareqMahmood Its ok

Comment: See my answer. It solves the problem

Comment: What should happen when you can't split string to strings with equal lengths (e.g. you want to break string `"abcdefghijklmn"` into 5 strings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what you asked

```
function breakString(str, items) {
  var result = str.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + Math.floor(str.length / items) + '}', 'g'));

  while(result.length > items) {
    result[result.length - 2] += result[result.length - 1];
    result.splice(result.length - 1, 1);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: The code breaks when (1) **zero** is passed as items parameter, (2) **array** or **object** is passed as str parameter.

Comment: @ArmanOzak Why do you expect it to work when you pass wrong parameters?

Comment: Thanks so much! This does break when the number you pass is less than the string length.

Comment: @Gothdo, I think a function with parameters should rather test the arguments first. Otherwise, there is a risk of ruining the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

This function does the job:

```
var brk = function(s,n){
    if(s.split && typeof n === "number") {
        var l = s.length,
            z = ~~(l/n),
            zx = (z*n<l) ? l-z*(n-1) : z;
            a = [];

        for(var i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
            a[i] = s.slice(i*z,i*z+z);
        }

        a[Math.ceil(n-1)] = s.slice(-zx);

        return a;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

You can test it with a console log:

```
console.log(brk("1234567890",3));
```

Comment: String characters disappear in your solution. You can try e.g. `brk("1234567890", 7) //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "90"]`

Comment: You are right; edited the related line. I do not believe it deserves the down vote though.