# Dynamic input box formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to format an `<input>` box using javascript / jquery.

**The Goal** - As the user types, add hyphens automatically after every third character.

```
123123123 becomes 123-123-123
```

I have a working code, but it is super slow and clunky. **I am looking for recommendations on how to improve the code**

```js
$('#serial').keyup(function(){

  $(this).val( $(this).val().trim() );

  var str = $(this).val();
  var newStr = str.replace(/-/g, "");

  var valuesArray = newStr.split("");
  var newVal = "";

  while ( i = valuesArray.shift() ){
    if(newVal.length === 3){
      newVal += "-";
    } else if (newVal.length === 7){
      newVal += "-";
    }
    newVal += i;
  }
  $(this).val(newVal);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="serial">Type something magical</label>
<input type="text" id="serial" name="serial">
```

Comment: your code is only adding hypen 2 times

Comment: Yea, I should note that the serial number is only 9 digits long. :)

Comment: the first line does not need to assign the value to the input control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` event istead of `keyup` it's very useful to track input fields changes :

```
$('#serial').on('input', function(){
```

**NOTE :** The code seems slow because `keyup` won't fire until you release the key, but you can type the next character before releasing the first.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update :**

You don't need any loop here, you can use `substr` to cut your string and insert the separator `-` and use `maxlength` to define the max number of charaters you want to contain your serial :

```js
$('#serial').on('input', function()
{
   var input_value = $(this).val().trim().replace(/-/g, "");
    
    if(input_value.length > 3){
      input_value = input_value.substr(0, 3) + '-' + input_value.substr(3);
    }
    if (input_value.length > 7){
      input_value = input_value.substr(0, 7) + '-' + input_value.substr(7);
    }
    
    $(this).val(input_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="serial" name="serial" maxlength="11">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/0zecps0f/), replaced [inefficient regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript) with substring

```
$('#serial').input(function(){

  $(this).val( $(this).val().trim() );

  var str = $(this).val().trim().split( "-" ).join("");
  var output = "";
  while ( str.length > 3 )
  {
   output += str.substring(0,3) + "-";
   str = str.substring(3);
  }
  output += str;

  $(this).val(output);

});
```

Comment: This Def works, but it appears to be a little slow as well. I do think the approach is better then mine; however, Zakaria's answer seems to be best so far.

Answer (score 1):

A little further optimization

```
$('#serial').on('input', function() {

  var str = $(this).val().trim();
  var i = 3;
  while (i < str.length) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == '-') {
      i += 4;
    } else {
      str = str.slice(0, i) + '-' + str.charAt(str.length-1);
    }

  }
  $(this).val(str);

});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h5hdvcwu/1/