# Splitting string with .match doesn't work inside a for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

Based on the accepted answer in [Split large string in n-size chunks in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript) I am trying to split a string from 1 to the number of characters it contains and push these into an array.

Here is my code:

```
function solve(s){
    var n = [];
     for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
       n.push(s.match(/.{1,i}/g));
     }
    return n
  };
```

If I run `solve("1341");` it returns `[null, null, null, null]`

However if I write my function without using the for loop, it does what I intended to do:

```
function solve(s){
    var n = [];
    n.push(s.match(/.{1,1}/g));
    n.push(s.match(/.{1,2}/g));
    n.push(s.match(/.{1,3}/g));
    n.push(s.match(/.{1,4}/g));
    return n
};
```

solve("1341"); returns `[["1", "3", "4", "1"], ["13", "41"], ["134", "1"], ["1341"]]`

Why is my code failing inside the for loop?

Comment: This has nothing to do with loops. Your regexes are different.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop `i` is a variable. When you use `/.{1,i}/` you insert the letter `i`, and not the value of `i` to the expression. To create a regular expression that includes the value of `i`, create the string using string concatenation or template literals, and then use the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor or factory on the string to convert it to the expression:

```js
function solve(s) {
  var n = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) {
    n.push(s.match(RegExp('.{1,' + i + '}', 'g')));
  }
  return n
};

console.log(solve("1341"));
```