# Split and replace text by two rules (regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

I trying to split text by two rules:

1. Split by whitespace
2. Split words greater than 5 symbols into two separate words like (`aaaaawww` into `aaaaa-` and `www`)

I create regex that can detect this rules (https://regex101.com/r/fyskB3/2) but can't understand how to make both rules work in (`text.split(/REGEX/`)

Currently regex - `(([\s]+)|(\w{5})(?=\w))`

For example initial text is `hello i am markopollo` and result should look like `['hello', 'i', 'am', 'marko-', 'pollo']`

Comment: Where's the `-` in `marko-` coming from?

Comment: It's divider, if word is too big program should split it into 2 words and add `-` to the first one  so user can understand that it's one word

Comment: What's the expected output for the input `hello i am mark-opollo`?

Comment: ['hello', 'i', 'am', 'mark--', 'opollo']

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to use `.match`: match up to 5 characters that aren't whitespace:

```js
const str = 'wqerweirj ioqwejr qiwejrio jqoiwejr qwer qwer';
console.log(
  str.match(/[^ ]{1,5}/g)
)
```

Comment: You're missing an edge case. It's trivial to add dashes to substrings that are exactly 5 chars long, but you can't assume that it was *longer* than 5 and therefore needs a dash.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to process the string before splitting (I'm a big fan of RegEx):

1- Search and replace [all the 5 consecutive non-last characters](https://regex101.com/r/j70eeh/2) with `\1-`.

The pattern `(\w{5}\B)` will do the trick, `\w{5}` will match 5 exact characters and `\B` will match only if the last character is not the ending character of the word.

2- Split the string by spaces.

```js
var text = "hello123467891234 i am markopollo";
var regex = /(\w{5}\B)/g;

var processedText = text.replace(regex, "$1- ");

var result = processedText.split(" ");

console.log(result)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
const str = "hello i am markopollo";
const words = str.split(/\s+/);
const CHUNK_SIZE=5;

const out = [];
for(const word of words) {
  if(word.length > CHUNK_SIZE) {
      let chunks = chunkSubstr(word,CHUNK_SIZE);
      let last = chunks.pop();
      out.push(...chunks.map(c => c + '-'),last);
  } else {
      out.push(word);
  }
}
console.log(out);

// credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29202760/65387
function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
  const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
  const chunks = new Array(numChunks)

  for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
    chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
  }

  return chunks
}
```

i.e., first split the string into words on spaces, and then find words longer than 5 chars and 'chunk' them. I popped off the last chunk to avoid adding a `-` to it, but there might be a more efficient way if you patch `chunkSubstr` instead.

regex.split doesn't work so well because it will basically remove those items from the output. In your case, it appears you want to strip the whitespace but *keep* the words, so splitting on both won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Uses the regex expression of @CertainPerformance = `[^\s]{1,5}`, then apply [regex.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), finally loop all matches to reach the goal.

Like below demo:

```js
const str = 'wqerweirj ioqwejr qiwejrio jqoiwejr qwer qwer'
let regex1 = RegExp('[^ ]{1,5}', 'g')

function customSplit(targetString, regexExpress) {
  let result = []
  let matchItem = null
  while ((matchItem = regexExpress.exec(targetString)) !== null) {
    result.push(
      matchItem[0] + ( 
        matchItem[0].length === 5 && targetString[regexExpress.lastIndex] && targetString[regexExpress.lastIndex] !== ' '
         ? '-' : '')
    )
  }
  return result
}
console.log(customSplit(str, regex1))
console.log(customSplit('hello i am markopollo', regex1))
```