# How to Reverse String in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string like below:

```
ABCDEFGH
```

And i want to reverse it like below:

```
GHEFCDAB
```

i have tried this:

```
  var str = "ABCDEFGH";
  var splitString = str.split("");
  var reverseArray = splitString.reverse();
  var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
```

And return like below:

```
HGFEDCBA
```

I Know it wrong, and it just reverse it one way. how to reverse string in javascript with that condition? Many thank before.

Comment: So, you want to reverse every couple of letters, but leave the two letters in each group in the same order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reverse a string in place in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958908/how-do-you-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-javascript)

Comment: @OscarPaz yes, thats right. can you help me please?

Comment: @PrestonGarvey wait, im still reading it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, using regex :
`let splited = str.match(/.{1,2}/g).reverse().join('');`

`str.match(/.{1,2}/g)` to transform `ABCDEFGH` to `[AB, CD, EF, GH]`
`reverse()` to transform `[AB, CD, EF, GH]` to `[GH, EF, CD, AB]`
`join('')` to transform `[GH, EF, CD, AB]` to `GHEFCDAB`

[You can take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

## Pairing string reverse

> Using empty String

```js
const str = 'ABCDEFGH'
var emptyStr = '';

for(let i = str.length; i>1; i--){
  emptyStr += str.slice(i-2,i)
  i--
}
console.log(emptyStr);
```

> using empty Array

```js
const str = 'ABCDEFGH'
const rev = str.split('');
const revStr = []

for(let i = str.length; i >=1; i--){
const strPair = rev.slice(i-2,i).join('');
  i--;
  revStr.push(strPair)
  }
console.log(revStr.join(''))
```

> Output: GHEFCDAB

Answer (score 0):

```
class RevStr{
 
    constructor(input){
        this.str =input;
    }

    reverseStr() {
        let str = this.str.match(/.{1,2}/g)
        let end = str.length-1;
        let start = 0;

        while (start < end) {
            let temp = str[start];
            str[start] = str[end];
            str[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        console.log(str.join(''));
    }

}
let s = new RevStr("abcdefgh");
s.reverseStr();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 simple solutions to reverse a string in JavaScript:

```js
// Solution-1: Using reverse() method
function reverseString1(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('')
}

// Solution-2: Using for loop
function reverseString2(str) {
    let reversed = ''; 

    for(let character of str) {
        reversed = character + reversed; 
    }

    return reversed;
}

// Solution-3: Using reduce() method
function reverseString3(str) {
    return str.split('').reduce((reversed, character) => character + reversed, '')
}

console.log("Solution 1: ", reverseString1("happy")); 
console.log("Solution 2: ", reverseString2("database")); 
console.log("Solution 3: ", reverseString3("loop"));
```