# Split Message of More than 2000 characters Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a role list command but turns out I have too many roles. Anyway to split the message into more. The roles are stored in an array. Btw I only want roles starting with A.

```
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(c => c.name.startsWith('A'))
```

Here is the error in console

```
Invalid Form Body content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.
```

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'rolelist',
    description: 'Sends A List Of Roles Availible In The Server',
    execute(message, args, client) {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
        const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.filter(c => c.name.startsWith('A'))
        if (colors.size < 1) {
            return message.channel.send('There are no roles starting with the letter A');
        }
        message.channel.send(roles.array().join(` \n`), {split:true,})
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoding to the docs you can split the messages:

`.send(data, { split: true })`

> If you weren't already aware, .send() takes 2 parameters: the content
> to send, and the message options to pass in. You can read about the
> MessageOptions type [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions). Using split: true here will automatically
> split our help message into 2 or more messages in the case that it
> exceeds the 2,000 character limit.

https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html#a-dynamic-help-command

Comment: It looks like you need to add at least one `\n`, https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/SplitOptions what on earth are you sending?

Comment: Its in the utils class, which you could import: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/b38f537da89e02d7cce0af508cd07d284e2fa8ec/src/util/Util.js#L56 though you could just do it yourself by [splitting the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033639/split-large-string-in-n-size-chunks-in-javascript) and sending multiple messages. Though it seems odd that your list has no newlines, how are you generating it and what format is it? its not simply JSON.stringify() is it?

Comment: I not sure, you might need open a new question for the mentions issue, you might be able to use backticks to wrap the roles so the `@` is escaped: '\`'+roles.array().join('\` \n')+'\`'