# Discord.py - auto-chunking text when sending large messages?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a large string I would like to send:

```
my_text = "...greater.than.4096.chars..."
embed = discord.Embed(title='Hello World')
embed.description = my_text
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However I get this error:
`In embed.description: Must be 4096 or fewer in length.`

Is there a way in `discord.py` to automatically split the string into multiple chunks to be sent?

[In discord.js, they have a way to do so like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809860/split-message-of-more-than-2000-characters-discord-js):

`.send(data, { split: true })`

Is there something similar for discord.py? Or do I have to write my own solution?

Answer (score 0):

Theres no built in way as far as I know in discord.py. But you can of course split it manually. Something like this should work?

```py
from math import ceil

for i in range(ceil(len(my_text) / 4096)):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Hello World')
    embed.description = (my_text[(4096*i):(4096*(i+1))])
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```